# Parsing Codable Responses with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I using the Alamofire Framework, but I don't understand why the variables below are empty.

json:

```
{
    "ret": true,
    "text": "Oke!",
    "data": {
        "email": “test@mail.com”,
        "nev": "text",
        "zip": "1234",
        "city": "London",
        "street": "text",
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "gdpr": "2"
    }
}
```

UserDataRootClass.swift:

```
struct UserDataRootClass : Codable {

        let data : UserDataData?
        let ret : Bool?
        let text : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case data = "data"
                case ret = "ret"
                case text = "text"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                data = try? UserDataData(from: decoder)
                ret = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .ret)
                text = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
        }

}
```

UserDataData.swift:

```
struct UserDataData : Codable {

        let city : String?
        let email : String?
        let gdpr : String?
        let nev : String?
        let phone : String?
        let street : String?
        let zip : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case city = "city"
                case email = "email"
                case gdpr = "gdpr"
                case nev = "nev"
                case phone = "phone"
                case street = "street"
                case zip = "zip"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                city = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .city)
                email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
                gdpr = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .gdpr)
                nev = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .nev)
                phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .phone)
                street = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .street)
                zip = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .zip)
        }

}
```

NetworkManager.swift:

```
func postLogin(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (UserDataRootClass?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(urlString).response {
            response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let loginRequest = try decoder.decode(UserDataRootClass.self, from: data)
               completion(loginRequest)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

LoginViewController.swift:

```
let networkManager = NetworkManager()
networkManager.postLogin(urlString: "http://demo.com") { (loginRequest) in

if((loginRequest?.ret)!) {
   print(loginRequest) // -> for log
   print(loginRequest?.data.phone)
   }

}
```

The log:

> UserDataRootClass(data: Optional(.UserDataData(gdpr: nil, email: nil,
>   zip: nil, nev: nil, phone: nil, city: nil, street: nil)), ret:
>   Optional(true), text: Optional("Oke!"))

The `loginRequest?.ret`, and `loginRequest?.text` is good, but `loginRequest?.data.email`, `loginRequest?.data.zip`... is empty (nil)

Comment: There is no need for `enum CodingKeys` and `init(from decoder: Decoder)` because, the keys match the properties exactly and you're not doing any specific handling in the `init`.

Comment: Declaring everything carelessly as optional reveals a big disadvantage: In case of an error nothing happens and you have no idea why. Remove all question marks and the `init(from decoder` methods and you will know at once what's wrong.

Comment: @vadian I've removed everything so the code runs perfectly. Thank you very much for the help, I would not have realized it myself.

Comment: The error was in the line `data = try? UserDataData(from: decoder)`. You have to decode `data` the same way as `ret` and `text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare `CodingKeys` `enum` when the `variable` name's of your `type` are same as the `json` keys in api response. For example, in your case you have named all variables(inside `UserDataRootClass` and `UserDataData`) same as their respective `json` key so you can remove those enums.

```
struct UserDataData : Codable {

        let city : String?
        let email : String?
        let gdpr : String?
        let nev : String?
        let phone : String?
        let street : String?
        let zip : String?
}

struct UserDataRootClass : Codable {

        let data : UserDataData?
        let ret : Bool?
        let text : String?
}
```

Also, you don't need to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {` until you have to do some customization on any attribute.